# Qt WebEngine can render without xcbglintegrations

Tags: c++, qt5, qtwebengine

I'm working on a Ubuntu 18.04 and Qt 5.12.4. I noticed that the QtWebEngine can draw even though the xcbglintegrations are missing. I'm not sure how the xcbglintegrations are working, if there available the OpenGL context could be intialized.

I take the Qt example (https://doc.qt.io/archives/qt-5.11/qtwebengine-webenginewidgets-stylesheetbrowser-example.html) and run it with Qt 5.12.4.
The WebEngine renders the Qt's webpage.
See:
[image]

But then I renamed the xcbglintegrations folder and I start it again.
There are some warning at the console:

```
QXcbIntegration: Cannot create platform OpenGL context, neither GLX nor EGL are enabled
Attribute Qt::AA_ShareOpenGLContexts must be set before QCoreApplication is created.
WebEngineContext used before QtWebEngine::initialize() or OpenGL context creation failed.
```

But this is not a problem for the WebEngine. It still renders the Qt's webpage.

See:
[image]

My question is, why is the rendering of the WebEngine working without xcbglintegrations?
And is it ok, to not deploy/use the xcbglintegrations? Does someone have expierence about that?
I've found that it works worse with the xcbgl, because then real OpenGL problems occur.
For example like these bug report from me:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-77922

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-77851